# The project could not be compiled

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Я пытаюсь создать проект на Unreal Engine 4. Ставлю в настройках c++, но получаю такую ошибку

```
The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?

TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Creating makefile for MyProject3Editor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject3Editor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:\Users\??䮭???\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject3\MyProject3.uproject" "C:\Users\??䮭???\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject3\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject3Editor\Development\MyProject3Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="C:\Users\??䮭???\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_UHT.txt" -installed
LogInit: Display: Loading text-based GConfig....
Reflection code generated for MyProject3Editor in 44,0581271 seconds
@progress pop
Building MyProject3Editor...
Using Visual Studio 2019 14.30.30706 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705) and Windows 10.0.19041.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Building 9 actions with 8 processes...
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0%
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 11%
  [1/9] Default.rc2
  @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 22%
  [2/9] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.cpp
  c1xx: fatal error C1083: ?? 㤠???? ??????? 䠩? ?஬????????? ??? ???????????: C:\Users\?????"??????????\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject3\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject3Editor\Development\Engine\SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.h.pch: No such file or directory,
```

Как я могу это исправить? VS уже обновлял, в отдельные компоненты лазил и отмечал то, что говорят в этой ссылке
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cant-package-my-project-netfxsdk/134855/2

Comment: Для начала убедитесь, что у вас в путях есть только ASCII идентификаторы. И что в VS стоит английский языковой пакет.

Comment: @user7860670 Английский поставил. А как проверить первое?

Comment: Ну вот же в вопросе `C:\Users\??䮭???` - видимо из-за каких-то проблем с кодировкой не ASCII 
 имя пользователя превратилось в крякозябры.

Answer (score 0):

Была точно такая же ошибка, помогла смена директории проекта Unreal

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]